# Polynomial roots problems.

Tags: polynomials

$$ X^5-55X+21$$
Prove that the given polynomial has 2 roots which satisfy the condition:
$$X_1X_2=1$$ 
and find them.
I have tried to make use of Viette's relations ,but couldnt get to a satisfying result.

Comment: $$(X-X_1)(X-X_2)=X^2-(X_1+\frac1{X_1})X+1$$

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed hint, please?

Comment: Attempt polynomial long division and show that there is no remainder for some $X_1$

Answer (score 10):

Hint: Check the polynomial GCD of the polynomial and its reverse, $21X^5-55X^4+1$.

Comment: This is the most systematic approach!

Answer (score 6):

The solution needn't be pulled out of hat like magic. Rather, we can discover it by exploiting innate *reciprocation symmetry*, i.e. if both $\,x_1$ and $\,x_2 = x_1^{-1}$ are roots of $f(x)$ then

$ 0 = f(x_2) = f(x_1^{-1})\,\Rightarrow\,0 = x_1^5f(x_1^{-1}) = 1\!-55x_1^4\!+21x_1^5 = \tilde f(x_1) = \,$ [reverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) of $f(x_1)$

Therefore $\,x_1\,$ is a root of $\,g(x) := \gcd(f(x),\tilde f(x))\,$ since $\,g(x)  = a(x) f(x) + b(x) \tilde f(x)$

by the Bezout gcd identity. By Euclid the gcd $= x^2\!-3x +\color{#c00}1$ whose roots have product $= \color{#c00}1$.

**Remark** $\ $ Such inversion symmetry often proves useful, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1290661/242)

Generally it is wise to attempt to  [exploit any innate symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+exploit+innate) before diving head-first into difficult brute force calculations. For example, for problems of the above sort it is much more efficient to compute polynomial *gcds* than to compute polynomial *factorizations*. Follow the prior link for many more examples of such symmetry exploits.

Answer (score 4):

$$ x^5-55x+21=(x^2-3x+1)(x^3+3x^2+8x+21)$$

It's not hard to prove that $x^3+3x^2+8x+21$ has only 1 real root, negative (just for curiosity, we won't need him), while $x^2-3x+1$ has 2 positive roots: $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

It turns out that these 2 roots are good for us:
$$\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\cdot\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}=1$$

Comment: By what means did you manage to write the given polynomial into that form?

Comment: I used a computer program, but without it I would try as follows:
there is no general method of finding the roots of polynomials of degree $>4$ (Galois theorem), so the natural way is to look for a decomposition;
since there are no easily seen "single roots", it remains to look for a decomposition of the form (deg 2 polynomial)*(deg 3 polynomial).

Comment: so:
$x^5-55x+21=(x^2+ax+b)(x^3+cx^3+dx+e)$ and we're dealing with a system of equation; $be=21$ so we may start with the most simply solutions - integers: $3\cdot 7$, $7\cdot 3$, $1\cdot 21$ or $21\cdot 1$, here the third one works fine (for these $b,e$ we can find other coefficients)

Comment: it was too long for a comment, so I split it in two comments

Comment: There is a hint inside the problem: words "find them".
It means that the roots can be found and written  -- this is a reason to look for a decomposition :-)